# Puedo usar x-editable con bootstrap 4.1.1?

Tags: ajax, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hola estoy trabajando con bootstrap 4.1.1 y necesito implementar el x-editable, peor no me funciona. Creo que es algo de compatibilidad. Me ayudan?

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46926354/x-editable-and-bootstrap-4

Comment: https://github.com/Talv/x-editable

Comment: aca los demos: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html